# Exception clogging up my IDE

Tags: c#, exception, system.net.webexception, suppression

I'm scanning for dead links on one of my pages. On one i get many "A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll" Dozens of them. How do i have MSVC# NOT display them? i am catching all of these exceptions since i am testing the link (in fact its called testStatus, request only head and returns a bool if its alive or not). How do i make the output nicer to read?

Comment: "How do i make the output nicer to read" -- what output are you talking about? Output on your webpage, or output in your debug window?

Comment: My debug window. MSVS Output panel

Answer (score 4):

**If they appear in the Output window:**
Right click anywhere in the Output window and uncheck "Exception Messages".

**If they appear in the Immediate Window:**
You may have enabled output redirection (Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window in Tools->Options->Debugging), you must then disable it inside the Output window too (because they are redirected from there).

---

But remember that you turned them off, sometimes they are quite useful.

Comment: It is useful but when i am searching for thousands of pages for bad links and catch the 404 http exception. They still show up and there are thousands of them. That completely ruins the usefulness. Especially since i catch and know about them.